# Creating a dictionary or ienumerable object

Tags: c#, dictionary, ienumerable

So I have a two columns from a database that will return all the products that are in my store and the department id's that are associated with the product.

What I want to do is create something using a list/dictionary/ienumerable set so that if I give a function a product id, it will spit out the department id.  At the moment I am having some troubles getting the declarations correct and need some help in that department.

First I have the base for the relationship between the Product and Category. Then I want `ProductCategoryCollection` to return the collection of all the mappings for each product and category/department. I am stuck in the second part and not really sure where to go from where I am at.

`helper.GetProductToCategoryMatching()` returns the rows from the database.

```
public class ProductAndCategoryID
{
    public ProductAndCategoryID(int product, int category)
    {
        this.productID = product;
        this.categoryID = category;
    }

    public int productID;
    public int categoryID;
}

public class ProductCategoryCollection : IEnumerable<ProductAndCategoryID>
{
    public ProductCategoryCollection()
    {

    }

    public List<ProductCategoryCollection> populate()
    {
        ShippingClassHelper helper = new ShippingClassHelper();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        List<ProductCategoryCollection> list = new List<ProductCategoryCollection>();

        ds = helper.GetProductToCategoryMatching();

        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {

        }

        return new List<ProductCategoryCollection>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do now is create a `ProductCategoryCollection` object inside of your loop and add it to your list.

```
public List<ProductAndCategoryID> populate()
    {
        ShippingClassHelper helper = new ShippingClassHelper();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        List<ProductAndCategoryID> list = new List<ProductAndCategoryID>();

        ds = helper.GetProductToCategoryMatching();

        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
          var pc = new ProductAndCategoryID();
          pc.ProductID = row[0];
          pc.CategoryID = row[1];

          list.Add(pc);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but I can't set the values for `ProductAndCategoryID` or, I guess do I need to if I am only return the two rows from the database?

Comment: What does the table that is returned look like?

Comment: `ProductID` `CategoryID` with corresponding relations. So Product # 660 is in Category 137, that would return `660` | `137`

Comment: All that I have currently is posted, like I said I am not really sure what I need to do or where to go.

Comment: I think the issue is that your ProductCategoryCollection is already an Enumberable and you are returning a List of those enumerables. I've updated my answer with a rewritten method that I think will work for you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and your requirements correctly, you would like to get a dictionary that maps a `ProductID` to a `CategoryID`, so that a lookup can be performed for the `CategoryID` of a given `ProductID`.

If that is a good translation of your problem, this is what you can do:

```
var productMap = new ShippingClassHelper()
    .GetProductToCategoryMatching()
    .Tables[0].Rows
    .ToDictionary(row => (int)row[0], row => (int)row[1]);
```

It makes the following assumptions:

- The "ProductID" field is an integer and the first field in a row.
- The "CategoryID" field is an integer and the second field in a row.
- Your dataset does not contain duplicate "ProductID" values.

Now you can use this dictionary to perform lookups. If you want to check if a given product id exists, you can do:

```
var containsProduct660 = productMap.ContainsKey(660);
```

If you want to retrieve the category id for a given product id you can do:

```
var categoryIdForProduct660 = productMap[660];
```